# htaccess mod rewrite. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I was wondering if someone could shed some light on where I'm going wrong here. I'm trying to make it so that if a user came to my site (in dev mode at the minute so localhost) and used the url for example http://localhost/example/aquery/string.

The url it would actually access it http://localhost/example.php?route=aquery/string. Is this possible? Here's what I have so far...

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?route=$2 [L]
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php

<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Any help appreciated.

Many thanks
James

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
Options All -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*)$ $1.php?route=$2 [L]
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
```

With `(.*?)` the first `()`$1 is only with first file name

Comment: Still didn't work, but I like the way you have shortened it though so I'll use that anyway! Thank you for answering though.

Comment: What is the problem ? Error message ?

Comment: Literally nothing. No error, no change at all in fact. I'll try and post a screen shot if I find out how!

Comment: Try with `RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*)$ $1.php?route=$2 [L,R=302]` to see the new url. (test)

Comment: Still nothing. The code behind the screen shotted page is simply print_r($_REQUEST);

Comment: I don't have a page under that name. The "social" part is the sub-directory for this project. Obviously once I have finished the project and I have hosted it to a real site it will be in root

Comment: But your `.htaccess` is in this `social` folder ?

Comment: It is yeah, everything is where it should be

Comment: Far too much to S/S, is there anything in particular you want from the info that I can S/S?

Comment: Look if the final link is correct with your test link. If it's the case it's ok with the htaccess code.

Comment: I'm really sorry, you've lost me here. None of the code for the htaccess has worked so far.

Comment: You ask me for .htaccess with your link. Now you have to do the php part wich work with your new url.

Comment: The htaccess code you sent doesn't work. I have tested it (on the php side) by checking for all types of requests and I'm receiving nothing